# Uncaught TypeError: this.files is undefined thrown by fr.readAsText(this.files[0]) (FileReader)

Tags: javascript, typeerror, filereader

I am experiencing an unexpected error when trying to load a javascript object using FileReader, unexpected because it works fine in another project, which is listed below. My intention is to perform a few operations on the javascript object right after reading it by executing a function that has several parameters, and that's why I changed the code structure because I didn't know how to put parameters in the code that works. Any tips are welcome.
Code that doesn't work

```
function wczytajSklad(sklad, id, objSklad, gdzie) {

            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function(){
                let wczytanySklad = fr.result;
                sklad = JSON.parse(wczytanySklad);
                ukryjInputFile(id);
                pokazCheckAndRadio(objSklad, gdzie);
            }
              
            fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
         
}
```

A place where i try to run function

```
<input type="file" name="gospodarze" id="wczytajSkladGospodarzy" onchange="wczytajSklad(skladGospodarzy, 'wczytajSkladGospodarzy', skladGospodarzy, 'skladGospodarzy')">
```

Code that works

```
document.getElementById('inputfile')
            .addEventListener('change', function() {
              
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function(){
                    wczytanyPlik = fr.result;
                    arrPoints = JSON.parse(wczytanyPlik);
                    rysuj();
                }
              
                fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
                
            })
```

Comment: What do you think `this` is?

Comment: To be honest, i don't know for sure, but i'm guessing it's a file i choose through input. Maybe?

Comment: The function isn't an object method, it doesn't receive a `this` value.

Comment: If you're calling it from an event listener, you need to pass `this` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i pass this as an argument and it works fine, big thank you.